# extension attributes

Tags: extension-attributes, magento2.2.0

I'm trying to extend Magento 2 api, I found this (https://github.com/magento-south/magento2-samples/tree/MAGETWO-55017/sample-external-links) but its not working..

After some fixes I got an error which I can't resolve on this line..

```
$metadata = $this->metadataPool->getMetadata(ExternalLinkInterface::class)
```

the message is

> "Unknown entity type: Seteskin\ExternalLinks\Api\Data\ExternalLinkInterface requested"

and my ExternalLinkInterface::class is 'Seteskin\ExternalLinks\Api\Data\ExternalLinkInterface'

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I got a fix for the sample-external-links (we dont even need that line). I'll do a pull request soon to that rep.